# heat map plugin from QGIS python console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I am trying to use the heat map plugin from the processing console. On the QGIS documentation it says the plugin uses Kernel Density Estimation. I have used the saga Kernel Density Estimation but do not get results that look similar to the heat map.
 How can I import the plugin into python console.
 For vector it's `from fTools import *`.
How can I use  raster plugins in processing i.e heat map plugin and georeferencer.

Comment: How to use processing via python is explained in the pyqgis cookbook

Comment: @kartoza-geek have you found an answer to this question or a workaround?

Comment: In QGIS3 it has been ported to the processing and easy to use in python